# Python Extract Range of Cells from Worksheet

Tags: python, excel, csv

I need to pull 16 rows from 2 columns in an excel spreadsheet with many worksheets.  I have figured out how to print the output from the place where the output needs to start, but I only want 16 rows.  My script prints all the way to the bottom.  Here's the script:

```
import xlrd  
import csv  

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('myworkbook.xlsx').sheet_by_index(16) 
mydata = open("myoutput.csv", 'w') 

try:  
    for rownum in range(47, wb.nrows):  
        ipaddr.write(str(wb.cell(rownum, 4).value)+ ", " +(wb.cell(rownum, 6).value)+"\n") 
finally:  
  mydata.close()
```

When I try to restrict the range like this:

for rownum in range(47, 63 wb.nrows):

it only prints row 47.  Any ideas how I can restrict the output to 16 rows? TIA

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import xlrd  
import codecs

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('myworkbook.xlsx').sheet_by_index(16) 
with codecs.open('myoutput.csv', 'w') as mydata:

for rownum in range(47, min(63,wb.nrows)):  
    mydata.write(str(wb.cell(rownum, 4).value) + ", " + str(wb.cell(rownum, 6).value) + "\n") 

mydata.close()
wb.close()
```